# Is Java's regex engine broken?

Tags: java, regex

I am writing some code to remove parentheses and their contents from a String, but this line isn't working properly:

```
line.replaceAll("\\Q"+matchp+"\\E", rep);
```

This should replace all of the found group, say "(group) more words" and the regex matched "(group)", then the String would become  rep + " more words". But the String is unaffected. Is quoting broken?

Comment: I bet you didn't re-assign the value to `line`.

Comment: It's time to read about String and immutability in Java....

Comment: unless you don't make any silly mistake java's `regex` engine is weak..

Comment: I was tired and forgot about immutable strings

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`replaceAll` is not in-place do it like so:

```
line = line.replaceAll("\\Q"+matchp+"\\E", rep);
```

Comment: I just realized that. I'm a little bit tired and forgot about immutable Strings.